# How casting internally works in JAVA? Both Primitive and Reference Casting

Tags: java, casting

Its theoretical question. I've been told that casting objects is not a best to do. So we use generics to do avoid it.

**1.But internally what happens? 
 2.Why its discouraged ?

 3.Where is the internal implementation of it in Java.**

Please explain with an example and also mention the methods / classes involved the process.

**Will I be able to override its default implementation? ( Just curious, Hope its not silly )**

Comment: for primitive typecasting is predefined as there are instructions i2b etc. you can go to this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Casting means slightly different things for primitive types and for reference types.

For primitive types, it can be used to convert a primitive of one type to another type, for example for [narrowing primitive conversions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3).

For reference types, it means that you tell the compiler "I have a variable of some type `A` but I want you to skip your normal type checking and treat it as if it is of type `B`". Casting reference types does not do any kind of conversion. It circumvents the compiler's normal type checking. A type check will still be done, but at runtime instead of at compile time. If the object is not of the right type, you'll get a `ClassCastException`.

Why is it discouraged: Because it makes your program less type-safe. The type system is there to help you catch mistakes, and casting means you are deliberately skipping a type check, and risk getting a `ClassCastException` when you run your program.

The internal implementation: This is just part of what the Java compiler does. You cannot override how casts work, and that would also not be very useful. (Changing what a cast means would change the rules of the Java programming language).